# Why does the style attribute not work on an element created with DOMParser?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I am attempting to use DOMParser to parse (X)HTML and then display it within the page. It appears to embed the correct elements in the page with the markup looking exactly as it should, but despite this they behave strangely (e.g. setting style='display: none' has no effect.)

What is going on here?

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var markup = '<p id="testp">Can you see me?</p>';
var doc = parser.parseFromString(markup,"text/xml");
document.body.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
document.getElementById('testp').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/57064q1u/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use text/html to use the style attribute. Otherwise you will only create a xml node.

```
var doc = parser.parseFromString(markup,"text/html");
```

Comment: And what if I am wanting to do this inside of an XHTML page that *IS* XML?

Comment: @Chris_F - then add an `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute to your `<p>` element. : https://jsfiddle.net/57064q1u/4/

Comment: @Alohci Is there a way to tell DOMParser what the default namespace should be, rather then creating an attribute for every element?

Comment: @Chris_F - I doubt it. But you don't need it on every element. On the root element will do, providing all the elements in the xml fragment are to go in the same namespace.